# Safari Can't Open the Page (Persistent Certificates Problem in Safari)

Tags: safari, keychain

I'm getting the error message "Safari can't open the page because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server." Yet the page runs perfectly on an iPad and other computers. I suspect a problem with Keychain/certificates but I can't pinpoint the problem. Any ideas?

Running macOS 10.12.1, and system date/time is correct.

Comment: Instead of saying  "_latest macOS update_" without any actual numeric designator, it's preferred that you actually state the version information, e.g macOS 10.12.1, so there is absolutely no ambiguity.

Comment: can you tell us the page url you are talking otherwise no one can try to reproduce or even test if he gets the same error

Comment: The URL is unsplash.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue on my machine by following these [instructions](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1353318-view-and-or-delete-crl-ocsp-cache) which seem to be different for 10.12 vs. prior versions of OS X. To summarize:

OS X 10.12

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Keychains/*/ocspcache.sqlite3 'DELETE FROM ocsp;'
```

For OS X 10.11 and earlier

```
sudo rm /var/db/crls/*cache.db
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't upvote 1000 times... Thanks a lot